# Rails: Mailer view with a different name from its action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-on-rails-3.1

**I want to find the action mailer corresponding to a specific mailer view**.
It seems that there are no mailer action with the name of the mailer view's name.
How can I find the mailer action in this case?

p.s
I am working on Rails code not written by me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a mailer action (with different name from the view), which rendered the view. The action didn't used the view's name explicitly when sending arguments to `render` function. The action received the view's name as a parameter, and then sent the parameter as an argument to the `render` function. The parameters to the action were sent from a model. This is why I couldn't find the view's name inside the `mailer` folder

Answer (score 0):

check `mailers` folder first then find the mailer class like:

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
...

end
```

then views are in `/views/user_mailer` folder

Comment: I didn't understand you answer. For instance, if the mailer view's name is 'foo' and its corresponding mailer action is 'bar', how could I have known the action name only by knowing its view's name?

Comment: if views in user_mailer/abc.html.erb then mailer action is in mailers/user_mailer.rb file with action name abc

Comment: Not in my case. I have a mailer view with a name that not match any mailer action. I searched for the name in all the mailers folder

Comment: then that mailer view is not used anywhere

Comment: if view is partial then it may be use in another mailer view

Comment: It is not a partial, and it is sent by some action

Comment: search file without extension in mailer directory.

Comment: try to send mail with mailer view and check logs with flow of files

Comment: How can I send a mail without knowing its action?

Comment: how do you know that that template is using in app?

Comment: if you do something on front end and mail sent with that template then you can say that template is using and then you can check logs

Answer (score 0):

You can search with the file name exclude the extension, like if you have an view file name `order.html.erb` you should search with `order` in `app/mailers` directory.

For example I have an `invoice mailer` as following in `app/mailers` directory

```
class InvoiceMailer < ActionMailer::Base
    def order
        #.... 
    end
end
```

and I have an `order.html.erb` corresponding view file in in `app/views/invoice_mailer` directory for order mailer.

Comment: did it. didn't find any mailer action matches the view's name excluding the extension

Comment: You can trace through you development server log, what is calling and rendering, then you can get an idea hopefully.